# Can I retrieve ebay listings data using list of item ids?

Tags: ebay-api

For example I have a bunch of ebay items ids and I need to retrieve all listing's data, including specifics fields. How can accomplish such task?

I've found, that ebay api had an 'GetMultipleItems' operation for the Trading API, but it was deprecated. Now only Shopping API has such operation, but the problem is that the Shopping API responses with a 'payload' ebay answer sometimes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GetItemRequest to get your item's detail by supplying item_id

e.g.

```
$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$eBay_auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ItemID>$itemid</ItemID>
<IncludeItemSpecifics>true</IncludeItemSpecifics>
<DetailLevel>ItemReturnAttributes</DetailLevel>
<ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>
<MessageID>$message_id</MessageID>
<Version>$api_version</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetItemRequest>​
EOD;

$response = $eBay->InitCurl($feed, "GetItem");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

Also refer This [eBay Doc](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html)

Or Try GetMyeBaySelling which gets 200 items in one call

```
$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$eBay->auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ActiveList>
<Sort>Title</Sort>
<IncludeNotes>FALSE</IncludeNotes>
<Pagination><EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>$pageNo</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
</ActiveList>
<HideVariations>FALSE</HideVariations>
<DetailLevel>ReturnSummary</DetailLevel>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<Version>$eBay->api_version</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetMyeBaySellingRequest>​
EOD;

$response = $eBay->InitCurl($feed, "GetMyeBaySelling");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetMyeBaySelling.html

Comment: the getItem operation retrieves only one item per request and it is not efficient, when you have to get data of 200 items.

Comment: this operation requires to provide a time window (StartTimeFrom,StartTimeTo)

Comment: No you don't if you use the feed I mentioned in the answer by changing DetailLevel to ReturnAll, It returns data for all the items 200 per call. It's working for me for last 1.5 years

Comment: Big thanks to you then. Will leave a comment as soon as I try it.

Comment: So I tried it and haven't managed to retrieve ALL listing data (itemSpecifics, partCompatibility) using GetMyeBaySelling call. This is necessary for my. Although I haven't provided such info in the topic's description - I will accept your answer as right one.